If $\Delta t_0 < \Delta t$ then does it mean that first light signal will reach receiver faster or earlier than second light signal?
Let we have light clock.

Light signal transmits from point A to point B (receiver).
In moving inertial frame we see first light signal. Clock shows $\Delta t_0$
In stationary inertial frame we see second light signal. Clock shows $\Delta t$
$\Delta t_0 < \Delta t$
If $\Delta t_0 < \Delta t$ then does it mean that first light signal will reach receiver faster or earlier than second light signal?
For clarity: both observers see that light signals arrive at point B at the same moment.If first observer see that first light signal arrived at point B then second observer see also that second light signal arrived at point B. But first observer's clock show time that less than second observer's clock time. Is it possible to say that first light signal will arrive faster or earlier than second light signal?
Thanks.

In both of the frames, there are two events, one being the emission of the light signal at A, the other being the arrival of the light signal at B. I think that your confusion arises from the fact that in the English language the phrase 'at the same moment' can have two different meanings. I will try to clarify that. The light only arrives at B once. It does not arrive at B in the stationary frame first and then later arrive at B in the moving frame, so in that sense you can say that it arrives at B at the same moment in both frames. However, the time interval between the light leaving A and arriving at B is longer in the frame through which the two points A and B are moving.

You are measuring both cases in you own reference frame, someone moving with B will also measure that it takes a time $\Delta t_0$. Because   $\Delta t_0 < \Delta t$, you see that in your reference frame it takes longer for the light ray to move from A to B, the famous time dilation for a moving clock.

I meant another thing when I asked my question. Namely - both observers see that light signals arrive at point B at the same moment. But first observer's clock show time that less than second observer's clock time. Is it possible to say that first light signal will arrive earlier than second light signal? @Pato Galmarini

what do you mean by  "both observers see it arriving at B at the same moment"? observers disagree on what is the "present"

If first observer see that first light signal arrived at point B then second observer see also that second light signal arrived at point B. @Pato Galmarini

But they don't agree on the time that happens, their clocks show different times

No. They see when light signal will arrive at point B. They doesn't need time indications. @Pato Galmarini

You stated they see it "at the same time", that doesn't make sense in special relativity, unless you refer to a single observer looking at two events, not at two observers looking at the same event.

If one of the observers see that light signal arrived at point B then it means that another observer see that light signal arrived at point B. @Pato Galmarini

yes, both see that, but you added "at the same time", which is meaningless, I don't know how else to explain it, go back to your books and think about it

Where did I say "at the same time" ? @Pato Galmarini

"at the same moment", which is the same, sorry if I changed the words, but the meaning is the same. Or correct me if you meant something different.

"at the same moment" doesn't mean "at the same time" . Am I wrong? @Pato Galmarini

It means the same to me, but there might be some subtle difference that you see and I fail to see

Yes. It differs to me. "at the same moment" = If one of the observers see that light signal arrived at point B then it means that another observer see that light signal arrived at point B. @Pato Galmarini

Yes, all observers agree on that.

I hope you find someone that understand your question, which you believe I did not

Thanks :) @Pato Galmarini
